# REST API - List view threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, list-view-threshold

We have a list that is now over 5000 and the following stopped working.  All the fields used in filters are indexed

```
var requestPendUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('LeaveRequest')/Items?$\
        filter=(((Manager0 eq '" + str + "') and (Status eq 'Pending'))\
            or ((AltManager eq '" + str + "') and (Status eq 'Pending'))\
            or ((Manager0 eq '" + str + "') and (ChangeStatus eq 'Pending'))\
            or ((AltManager eq '" + str + "') and (ChangeStatus eq 'Pending')))&$\
        select=Id&$\
        top=500";   

    var ajaxPendCount = $.ajax({
        url: requestPendUri,
        async: false,  //pass value outside of ajax
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            myCount = data.d.results.length;
        },
        error: function (data) { alert("Failed to count items.");   }
    });
```

I've read through [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fmanage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Each view is filtered and columns are indexed but still not sure how to work around the issue with REST.

**EDIT**
I typed  `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('LeaveRequest')/Items?$filter=(((Manager0 eq 'first.last@tenant.com') and (Status eq 'Pending')) or ((AltManager eq 'first.last@tenant.com') and (Status eq 'Pending')) or ((Manager0 eq 'first.last@tenant.com') and (ChangeStatus eq 'Pending')) or ((AltManager eq 'first.last@tenant.com') and (ChangeStatus eq 'Pending')))`

replacing all `first.last@tenant.com` with actual email address but IE just displayed `The website cannot display the page.

But, it seems to display data if I break it down to `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('LeaveRequest')/Items?$filter=((Manager0 eq 'first.last@tenant.com') and (Status eq 'Pending')) or ((Manager0 eq 'first.last@tenant.com') and (ChangeStatus eq 'Pending'))`

and
`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('LeaveRequest')/Items?$filter=((AltManager eq 'first.last@tenant.com') and (Status eq 'Pending')) or ((AltManager eq 'first.last@tenant.com') and (ChangeStatus eq 'Pending'))`

Comment: Have ypu checked if the records returned by the filtered view are less than 5000?

Comment: Yes, we only have 5016 records in list so far and there are only less than 100 pending items.

Comment: Did you try hitting your url in the browser? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: Should I be looking for anything specific? It says displaying 100/100 - doesn't really give me any hints if there's an error.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the result in browser along with your url?

Comment: @harshalgite I posted the image from IE and message from Edge. I also tried Chrome and its a long list of text/xml.

Comment: First of all you need to configure your IE to view sharepoint rest results in your IE. Go to IE options => content => check box for the option feed contents........ should be checked => then click apply and ok. Then try hitting your url

Comment: I unchecked the option for "turn on feed reading view" and pasted this URL `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('LeaveRequest')/Items?$filter=Status eq 'Pending'` its a long list of xml and I dont see any errors.  I posted only the top part.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it change the results if you modify your filter like  `$filter=(Status eq 'Pending' or ChangeStatus eq 'Pending) and (Manager0 eq '" + str + "' or AltManager eq '"+ str + "')` ?

Comment: Yes, it gave me 500 pending items when I don't have any pending leave requests to approve.  And, `var str = fixedEncodeURIComponent(_spPageContextInfo.userEmail);`

Comment: The long list of xml is your query result. If you get list items in the xml that means your query url is working and the error is somewhere else. You can try debugging your ajax call and by reducing the filters in the query.

Comment: @Tamras What type of columns are `Manager0` and `AltManager`? Single line of text? If they're "person or group" columns you'll want to format the query differently.

Comment: @Thriggle they are single line (Manager0) and choice (AltManager). The choice is a lookup field in InfoPath that retrieves the data from Manager0

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [search API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview) to get the items based on your filters and then you can manipulate the items in the result source to what you want to do.

Comment: I've never used search API but will look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.